# another version of this application must be uninstalled prior to deploying this apk file

Tags: android, version-control, version

I am trying to update my application in android but when install it, this message appears in device:

```
another version of this product is already installed prior to deploying this apk file.All data of this application will be lost. Do you want to proceed?
```

I want to install new version of app and replace to other version without this message.

Comment: Are you updating through ADB?

Comment: No. I want to install it without ADB.

Comment: find my solution. it was for that keystore in new project was different by old version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using adb to install your apk you should add "-r" option as follows :

> adb install -r yourApk.apk

If you are trying to download from somewhere and install it, you should uninstall previous version manually or you can use

> adb uninstall -k "packagename"

-k is for keeping the data and cache of your application.

Comment: no I dont use ADB for install. I generated apk file and want to install in genymotion or mobile without ADB.